# Question about the damaged rim and tire

Tags: tires, wheels, sidewall-damage

[image][image]

First timer here and I ran over something on the highway and this is the damage I got..... should I get the rim replace or is still OK to drive on

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 3):

You need to replace the tire and the rim or, replace the tire and get the rim professionally repaired - which will need welding, then machining, checking for roundness and then the new tire fitting and balancing.

Do NOT drive on this as it is - fit the spare...